# buttons check the correct answer objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsstring, uibutton, nsarray

I have one UIViewController and inside I have NSArray that I put my correct answer,and also I have 3 buttons, and 3 NSArray for their titles, I want to check if my buttons title was equal to the correct answer then goes to the correct page else goes to the wrong page

would you please help me to this implementation:

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
NSString *correctOne = @"test1";
NSString *correctTwo = @"test2";
NSString *correctThree = @"test3";
NSString *correctFour = @"test4";
NSString *correctFive = @"test5";
NSString *correctSix = @"test6";
NSString *correctSeven = @"test7";
NSString *correctEight = @"test8";



correctComments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: correctOne, correctTwo, correctThree, 
correctFour, correctFive, correctSix, correctSeven, correctEight, nil];

int rand = arc4random()%8;
  NSString *correct = [correctComments objectAtIndex:rand];
[test setTitle:(firstAnswer) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[test setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[test setTag:0];

[ansONE setTitle:(secondAnswer) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ansONE setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[ansONE setTag:1];

[ansTWO setTitle:(threeAnswer) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ansTWO setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[ansTWO setTag:2];

 - (IBAction)suivant:(id)sender {
```

//MY Question is how should I check my button title and correctComments

```
 }
```

Comment: You should really refactor all this into an `NSArray` and loops...

Comment: The code is not the point and refactoring does not alter the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 no way to use this code?

Comment: @iMartin I know, I just wanted to teach something good to OP.

Comment: @adam This code is not complete, so to judge it you will have to copy&paste exactly what you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)suivant:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int correctIndex = ...;

    BOOL thisIsTheCorrectButton = (button.tag == correctIndex);
    // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to **store correct answer** from your code snippet to a property:

```
self.correctAnswer = correct;
```

Then **do the comparision** of those strings:

```
- (IBAction)suivant:(UIButton *)sender {
    // You wanted to check for title:
    if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:self.correctAnswer]) {
        // Correct...
    }
    else {
        // Wrong...
    }
}
```

Comment: After this line in your example: `NSString *correct = [correctComments objectAtIndex:rand];`